# Get url after url rewrite on IIS+PHP?

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

My IIS rewrites http://example.com/wiki/Main (url before rewrite) to http://example.com/w/index.php?title=Main (url after rewrite).

In index.php, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `wiki/Main`.

I use Windows 2008 Server, IIS 7, PHP 5.4. The rewriting tool is IIS URL Rewrite Module 2. I'm new to PHP, IIS, and website stuff.

Does `REQUEST_URI` refer to the url before rewrite or after rewrite?

If `REQUEST_URI` is the url before rewrite, how can I get the url after rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the $_GET global array:

```
$URL = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?'; // index.php?
for ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    $URL .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
```

Or something like that. Basically, all URL `=` associations are stored in $_GET.

Comment: So REQUEST_URI refer to the url before rewrite?

Comment: By all appearances, yes. I wouldn't know for a fact, unfortunately.